# How to compare ints stored in linked lists - Java

Tags: java, linked-list, compare

I'm looking for some advice on a Java assignment.  What I'm asked to do is perform different operations on numbers that are stored in a linked list, with each digit in a separate node.  The point is to write a program that can do arithmetic on numbers that are very very large.

The particular problem that I'm looking for help on is for writing a method that compares two numbers, similar to regular compareTo() method for ints.  It should return -1 if this.num < num, +1 if this.num > num, and 0 if they are equal.

What's making this difficult for me is the fact that the assignment specifies that the linked lists should store the numbers in reverse order.  For example, the linked list for the number 145 would look like:

5 => 4 => 1 => null

This makes it easier to add numbers together but it's making it a headache for me when trying to compare.  Here's what I've come up with, the comments explain how it's supposed to work.

```
public int compareTo(LLNum list)
{ // Compares two numbers.
  // If the two numbers are of a different length, clearly the shortest is the smallest.
  // If the two numbers are of equal length, call traverseToCompare to do the comparison.
  if (this.len > list.len)
  {
    compareResult = 1;
  }
  else if (this.len < list.len)
  {
    compareResult = -1;
  }
  else if (this.len == list.len)
  {
    traverseToCompare(this.head, list.head);
  }

  return compareResult;
}


public void traverseToCompare(ListNode node1, ListNode node2)
{ // In the case that both numbers are of the same length, recursively traverse the list.
  // compare each digit individually while unwinding the stack.
  // Once two digits are found to be different, break out of the unwinding (Note: I could not find a way of breaking out)
  // Since the dominant digit is at the tail end, this ensures the least number of   comparisons.
  if (node1 == null || node2 == null) 
  { // Base case. Handles the case where both numbers are identical.
    compareResult = 0;
    return;
  }
  traverseToCompare(node1.getNext(), node2.getNext());
  if (node1.getItem() > node2.getItem())
  {
    compareResult = 1;
  }
  if (node1.getItem() < node2.getItem())
  {
    compareResult = -1;
  }

  return; 
}
```

The numbers being in reverse order is what pulled me towards recursion.  I thought I would recursively traverse the list and then compare each digit on the way out, and somehow break out of the recursion at the first digits that are not the same.  I realize this is not a usual way to use recursion but I wasn't sure how else to do it.  Is there a way I could break without just throwing an exception? I think that might be a little too sloppy.  Or any suggestions on how to do this without recursion?

Please don't just give me some code to copy and paste.  I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to do this I would first check the lengths of both lists (like you did). If they're equal, a better way to do the comparison would be to create an iterator for each list. You can then increment the iterators at the same time and compare the values at that position in the linked lists. Doing it this way, you can simply stop comparing the lists once you have determined that one contains a larger number than the other.

Comment: Is there a way to do this considering that the numbers are stored in reverse order? It would be easy with a doubly linked list, but we have to be using a singly linked list.  The first digit I want to be checking is the tail, which I do have a reference to, but then I'm not sure how I can traverse backwards from the tail.

Comment: Oh I see the problem. Well I think that Rai's answer is the way to go then. I see you say you cannot use strings. The only option you really have in that circumstance is to fully iterate through the list each time. The saving grace is that you could keep track of how far you have to iterate each time (since each time you perform a comparison you'd have to iterate through one less element). And of course if you find that one list is larger than the other you wouldn't have to do any more comparisons. You could do your recursion idea too.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to traverse the list for each number and construct the number and then compare the 2 numbers.

The way to construct a number from the list would be

```
int i = 0
int f = 1
Do while GetNext() <> Null
    i = i + GetCurrentItem() * f
    f = f * 10
End Do
```

For eg. if the number is 145, then the list would have 5->4->1

So running the above code

```
i = 0
f = 1

i = i + 5*1 = 5
f = f * 10 = 10

i = i + 4*10 = 45
f = f * 10 = 100

i = i + 1*100 = 145
f = f * 10 = 1000
```

So it comes out with i = 145.

Comment: And what happens when it overflows? I'm pretty sure that's part of the point of the assignment and will, therefore, certainly be tested.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been much easier to do using plain String; as you could store data of any length. But anyway the requirement is for LinkedList :

Now as the data is stored in revers order; this means you can't decide response of `compareTo` method until you go through the complete list, as most significant data is stored at last position.

```
  5 --> 4  --> 1    == 145
  1 --> 4 --> 5     == 541
```

So read through the whole least; then you can store the value in a **String** and then decide `compareTo` method result.

**traverseToCompare** method is called for same length items. So you can write your own algorithm to compare two numbers stored in **String**.

**Edit** 
If String is not allowed

Then will suggest you to do the same thing manually; iterate through the whole list compare the last node, if last node is same then compare the previous node and so on...

Comment: I should have specified, we are not allowed to use Strings :S

Comment: then you will have to do some more dirty job :D . Updated in the Edit section.

Answer (score 0):

In traverseToCompare you will need to take care of some cases.
It will be better and clean if you do not use the recursion.
Following can be a solution

```
boolean areSame = true;
boolean digitDiffer = false;
int compareResult = 0;
int length = node1.length
for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
{
   if(!digitDiffer && ((node1.getItem() == node2.getItem()))
   {
     continue
   }
   else
   {
      digitDiffer = true;
      if(node1.getItem() >= node2.getItem())
      {
         compareResult = 1
      }
      else
      {
        compareResult = -1;
      }
   }
}

return compareResult;
```